# I having Problem on Installing Microsoft SQL Server Developer Edition 2017

Tags: sql-server

[image]

I am not sure what is the problem of why I can't  install the software

Comment: The error tells you precisely what the issue is.

Answer (score 0):

You should run this installation as Administrator.

To do it you must right-click on your installation file in Explorer and choose **"Run as Administrator"**.